# How to read records in a file, one by one

Tags: node.js

I have a text file with multiple JSON documents on it, the JSON docs are not separated by new lines but instead they are separated by two new lines and a custom tag something like this

```
\n
@RECORD@SEPARATOR@
\n
```

What is the best way to read one by one on a stream, I am a complete node beginner and want to find the best way to do this.

Comment: show us what you've tried, and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('yourfile.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  var docs = (data
    .toString()
    .split('\n')
    .filter(function(line) {
      return line.trim() !== '';
    })
    .map(function(line) {
      // Do something else here depending on the exact format of your data
      return 'A non-empty line: ' + line;
    })
  );

  console.log(docs);
});
```